# Are Pure Vegetable Glycerine or Propylene Glycol safer to vape then standard vape juice?

Tags: e-cigarette-vape

I noticed some vape stores offer Pure Vegetable Glycerine(C3H8O3) or Pure Propylene Glycol(C3H8O2).

Is pure [VG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glycerol) or [PG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propylene_glycol) (see also: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QJ--FU0T7xo)) safer to vape than nicotine-less e-liquid? E-cigarettes are debatable less harmful than cigarettes according to USA [cdc.gov](https://www.cdc.gov/tobacco/basic_information/e-cigarettes/about-e-cigarettes.html#:%7E:text=Top%20of%20Page-,Are%20e%2Dcigarettes%20less%20harmful%20than%20regular%20cigarettes%3F,in%20smoke%20from%20regular%20cigarettes.&text=However%2C%20e%2Dcigarette%20aerosol%20is%20not%20harmless.) (see also: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Pwj6BuS8Ds)).

The obvious answer would seem to be yes because it contains no additives but after further review, I'm not certain what [there](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuSV3.jpg) is in e-liquids. E-liquids contain Natural Flavoring(no specifics), Artificial Flavoring, nicotine, PG, and VG typically.

Comment: What does "nicotineless e-liquid" contain? And without asking readers to watch a video advertising a company that sells stuff, what do VG and PG contain? Prior research is required here.

Comment: @ChrisRogers I have removed the link.  The drop down have multiple e liquids listed.

Comment: In fairness, @CareyGregory the link, which has been subsequently removed, was selling liquid which was labelled as not containing other ingredients found in many other nicotineless e-liquid. Although I agree that prior research must be shown for [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask]

Comment: The youtube links saved the question from closure, but they earned it a downvote.  If you're asking which of the substances is safer than the others you should at least be able to tell us what's in the choices without directing us to videos to watch.

Comment: Thank you for replacing the youtube links. I retracted my downvote. But now I'm left wondering if there's any difference between "nicotine-less" e-liquid and any other e-liquid aside from the nicotine. I wouldn't be surprised to learn they all buy the base product from a few suppliers and it's all the same stuff until they add their flavors, nicotine, or whatever.

Comment: Please try to limit usage of subscript and superscript links as they can be difficult to navigate on small screens such as mobile phones

Comment: @CareyGregory they are the same. It's all the same base (from various manufactures). Some do mix their own base, like a bit more percent of this and that and so on but in the end its all the same

Answer (score -1):

VG and PG are the main ingredients of almost all liquids you can buy. 
The 'pure' ones you mentioned are just for people who want to make their own flavored liquids at home (the big bottles of pure VG and PG). 
 Ready to vape liquids can contain many different flavors, natural ones like terpene and artificials as well and nicotine (either free-base or salt).
All in all its a bit difficult because its not only about the raw ingredients in the liquids but which 'chemical components' are created during heating them in your vape. (I'm not aware of many studies touching this topic but if you search a bit, you might find a few) But as less you heat (e.g. pure VG/PG) as less can be 'created' during heating.
But vaping pure VG/PG doesn't taste/feel good

Comment: VG is sweet so I’m no sure if you are right about that.

Comment: @William is do have a kinda sweet taste but it still does not taste very well when vape pure. Hard to describe the taste but I would not recommend it. But maybe thats also a personal taste thing. Have you ever vaped it pure?

Comment: I don’t care for the flavor in vapes.  I’m just curious what is the safest.  Flavor is no concern.

Comment: @William the safest is not to vape at all

Comment: please refer back to the CDC safer/safest less harmful are all debatable but important.